# Drop down menu works well in Firefox but not reliably in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drop down menu using JavaScript. It works reliably in Firefox (version 57). However, in Chrome (version 62) the drop menu only appears if you first click elsewhere on the page, and then on the menu icon / button.  I am using jQuery 3.2.1, and Bootstrap 2.3.2.

```js
var shown;

$(function() {
  shown = false;
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.id == "button") {
    if (shown)
      $("#dropdown").hide();
    else
      $("#dropdown").show();
    shown = !shown;
  } else if (shown) {
    $("#dropdown").hide();
    shown = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="icon">
  <button id="button">
    <img src="cogwheel.png">
  </button>
  <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <a href="todo2">Register</a>
    <a href="todo1">Login</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet. It appears to work fine for me in Chrome 62 on all clicks

Comment: Why not use `select`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: @StephanBijzitter because it appears to be a menu that the OP wants to put some custom styling on. It's a very common technique

Comment: @tyebillion unlikely as JS isn't async.

Comment: Are you completely sure you have to click elsewhere first, and then you can open the menu by clicking anywhere in the `<button>`? Tested in Chrome 62 and I cannot reproduce. There is, however, an issue when you click on the `<img>` inside the `<button>`. Can you test again? Clicking the edge of the `<button>` outside the `<img>` should work on first click. Any clicks on the `<img>` inside the `<button>` should be ignored.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you can style select and option just the same, and still have proper a11y support

Comment: `you can style select and option just the same` No you can't. Not even close, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the code provided in Chrome 62 and Firefox 57. I cannot reproduce your described behavior:

> ...in Chrome (version 62) the drop menu only appears if you first click elsewhere on the page, and then on the menu icon / button

There is, however, an issue when you click the `<img>` inside the `<button>` which is caused by the `<img>` being the event target in Chrome. You can solve this by changing your condition to check if `#button` is the target itself *or the parent node of the target*.

So change `if (event.target.id == "button")` to `if (event.target.id == "button" || event.target.parentNode.id == "button")`.

```js
var shown;

$(function() {
  shown = false;
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.id == "button" || event.target.parentNode.id == "button") {
    if (shown)
      $("#dropdown").hide();
    else
      $("#dropdown").show();
    shown = !shown;
  } else if (shown) {
    $("#dropdown").hide();
    shown = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="icon">
  <button id="button">
    <img src="cogwheel.png">
  </button>
  <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <a href="todo2">Register</a>
    <a href="todo1">Login</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this was the issue.